# Is there a general way in C to make a number greater than 64 bits or smaller than 8 bits?

Tags: c, int

> First of all, I am aware that what I am trying to do might be outside the C standard.

I'd like to know if it is possible to make a `uint4_t`/`int4_t` or `uint128_t`/`int128_t` type in C.

I know I could do this using bitshifts and complex functions, but can I do it without those?

Comment: No, you can't..

Comment: The difficult part would be to redefine arithmetic operators for these types.

Comment: Can someone post a generalized answer saying why or why not?

Comment: Do you have a brick in your backpack? No? Why not? Because you just don't have it!

Comment: I assume by "complex" you mean complicated, rather than functions taking `std::complex<double>` or such?

Comment: @Hurkyl, in C there is no `std::complex<double>`

Comment: @Colin: It does have the "or such".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bitfields within a structure to get fields narrower than a uint8_t, but, the base datatype they're stored in will not be any smaller.

```
struct SmallInt
{
   unsigned int a : 4;
};
```

will give you a structure with a member called a that is 4 bits wide.

Comment: This isn't standard C. You can't portably use `uint8_t` for bit-fields.

Comment: Here is a standard reference for that: `C11  6.7.2.1  5` *"A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is
implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted."* This restriction was lifted in C++: `C++14  9.6  3` *"... A bit-field shall have integral or enumeration type ..."*.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, Both, Updated.

Comment: @Colin__s if I pack this structure, will it take up 4 bits?

Comment: @MarkYisri, no, it will take up at minimum the `sizeof(unsigned int)`. 
`sizeof(char)` is 1 due to the standard, and char bits is at minimum 8 due to the standard.

Comment: @Colin__s then what is the use of a bitfield?

Comment: @MarkYisri you could pack 8 * 4 bit values inside one 32 bit value without having to do the bit twiddling yourself.

Comment: @Colin__s and then do a bitmask to ensure only the correct 4 bits are visible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131169/discussion-between-mark-yisri-and-colin-s).

Comment: This answer does not address OP's 1st half question "Is there a general way in C to make a number greater than 64 bits ...?".  Curious that this answer is accepted.

Comment: @chux I accepted it because he says that you cannot make it smaller in his answer. "_but, the base datatype they're stored in will not be any smaller._"

Comment: @MarkYisri Hmm. "but, the base datatype they're stored in will not be any smaller." does not address the issue to "Is there a general way in C to make a number greater than 64 bits ...?"  Oh, well.

Comment: @chux my question also has "_or smaller than 8 bits?_"

Answer (score 3):

Individual storage units (bytes) are no less than `CHAR_BITS` bits wide<sup>1</sup>; even if you create a `struct` with a single 4-bit bitfield, the associated object will always take up a full storage unit.

There are multiple precision libraries such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) that allow you to work with values that can't fit into 32 or 64 bits.  Might want to check them out.

---

1. 8 bits minimum, but may be wider.

Comment: can GMP do 4 bits?

Comment: @MarkYisri: It can certainly represent *values* that are at most 4 bits wide, but so can the native integer types.  Again, no *object* can be less than 8 bits wide.  MP libraries are geared more for working with values that *can't* fit in the native types.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, if you want very wide numbers (but that is *not specified* in standard C11) you probably want to use some [arbitrary-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) arithmetic *external* library (a.k.a. bignums). I recommend using [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

In some cases, for tiny ranges of numbers, you might use bitfields inside `struct` to have tiny integers. Practically speaking, they can be costly (the compiler would emit shift and bitmask instructions to deal with them).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267512/841108) mentioning `__int128_t` as an extension in some compilers.