# In C, can you have a 128-bit bitfield

Tags: c, int

Is the following code legal?

```
struct BigInt {
     uint64_t a : 128;
};
```

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem. Why do you **think** you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bitfield must fit within a single `int`, so you're out of luck unless `int` is 128 bits on your platform.

(You were also missing a `;` at the end of the `struct` prior to the edit.)

Comment: Bitfield base types `_Bool`, `int` and `unsigned int` are guaranteed. So on an implementation with 128 bit `int`, there will be a 128 bit bitfield. An implementation can provide more types. Considering some support a 128 bit integer on smaller architectures, there might be also a 128 bit bitfield.

Answer (score 0):

Not legal in standard C11 (on most platforms; in principle, an `int` might be 128 bits, but I never met a platform having that). Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (draft specification).

But on *some platforms* recent compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 6) provide [`__int128`  as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#_005f_005fint128). You won't use that as a bitfield, but as some kind of integral type.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265826/841108) answer to a related question.

Comment: Read the entire standard? How about a snippet?

Comment: 1) The standard does allow 128 bit `int`, so there can be 128 bit bit-fields. 2) The standard allows an implementation to support other types for bit-fields. So `__int128` can be used as bitfield. Conclusion: the standard does not disallow it! (The actual question would be what use it would have).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite WDYM what use? Have you seen transport protocol field sizes??